# shell programming what does this if condition means

Tags: shell

I have read some introductory tutorials on bash programming, but the examples they give are fairly simple.

I have a script with the following line

```
if [[ "${USE_HMI:=OFF}" == "OFF" ]]; then
```

What does that mean? I can see that it is comparing for equality to a string "OFF" but what confuses me is the ":=" (which I suppose is an assigment) into a comparison...

Can someone help me interpret this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it means you are assigning by default the value *OFF* on the environment variable *$USE_HMI*.
If you don't set the USE_HMI environment variable, the default value will be *OFF*, and the if statement will be true.

You can quickly test if on your console:

```
# Null environment variable
$ unset USE_HMI
$ echo ${USE_HMI}

# Print with default value
$ echo ${USE_HMI:=OFF}
OFF

# Set value and print with default value
$ export USE_HMI=ON

# Default value will be ignored because you have set the environment variable
$ echo ${USE_HMI:=OFF}
ON
```

Comment: With the colon, it also assigns the "OFF" value if the variable is set with an empty string: `USE_HMI=""; echo "${USE_HMI=OFF} -> $USE_HMI"; echo "${USE_HMI:=OFF} -> $USE_HMI"`